# TypeError: OAuth2Strategy requires a clientID option passport-google-oAuth20

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

```
//jshint esversion:6
require('dotenv').config();
const express= require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const session = require('express-session');
const passport = require("passport");
const passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose")
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;
const findOrCreate = require('mongoose-findorcreate');

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({

    clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    
    clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/google/secrets",
    userProfileUrl:"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
    User.findOrCreate({ googleId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
      return cb(err, user);
    });
  }
));

app.get('/auth/google',
  passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ["profile"] })
  );
```

This is my whole code installed dotenv package tooo
and added my clientID in .env file but I get this error .
I am using passport-google-OAuth20

Comment: Did you find any solution to this

Comment: I'm also stuck with this same error.  And in my app.js file, I'm using the code pasted from the tutorial that I'm trying to complete.  So I think it's a problem in my .env file.

Answer (score 0):

I had also faced the same problem earlier.

1. Check whether the `.env` file is global initialized i.e, the file is in root directory or not by just create a `.env` file in root directory,

Just `console.log(process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID);`

If it gives undefined then it implies that the file is not in correct directory So, change the directory.

In case it doesn't work just install the package once again `npm install dotenv`.

Your problem will be solved by this.